# Matlab Report Generator Headers in Word (RTF)

Tags: matlab, ms-word, report, generator, doc

I am trying to solve one really common problem with Matlab Report Generator.

**Problem:** I cannot create header in Matlab Report Generator for MS Word documents

**Matlab version:** 7.11.0 (R2010b)

**MRG version:** 2.9 - 03-Aug-2010

So do you know how to solve it in Matlab R. Gen.? Or do you know if it is possible to add some "code" to *.doc file to generate header and footer?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. It looks like this is only supported for PDF, see http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/rptgen/ug/using-stylesheet-cells-to-manage-pdf-report-header-and-footer-content.html.

Comment: I know, It was very easy to work with that as PDF, but no chance for word. I do not know why, it must be simple to add header to word, don't you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after one week of searching and coding, I have an conclusion:

There are two ways how to generate documents in Matlab:

1. Use ActiveX "server" in Matlab to automatize the "hand work".
2. Write the .RTF/.DOC/.DOCX straight via their standards.

Matlab Report Generator is good for generating documents about your work in Matlab, when you do not need extended formats.